# FS2 (Functional Streams for Scala) how to do group(n)

Tags: scala, akka-stream, fs2

How to group elements? Possible solutions:

- `chunkLimit`
- `segmentLimit`
- `segmentN`
- `groupAdjecentBy`

Which don't do exactly that.

i'm looking for something like [grouped](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#grouped) in [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/index.html)

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

`segmentN` is what you want to use - it gives you a `Segment` which you can `seg.force.toVector`,

`myStream.segmentN(limit).map(seg => seg.force.toVector)` yields a `Stream[F, Vector[A]]`